# Error System.TypeLoadException: 'AuthenticateRequestAsync' how to solve this?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

Hi i have this error :

```
Gravité Code    Description Projet  Fichier Ligne   État de la suppression
Erreur      System.TypeLoadException: La méthode 'AuthenticateRequestAsync' du type 'AzureAuthenGraph.AzureAuthenticationProvider' de l'assembly 'AzureAuthenGraph, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' n'a pas d'implémentation.
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   à MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
   à MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
Error generating functions metadata
    AzureAuthenGraph    C:\Users\*****\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.13\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets    39
```

my code :

```
    public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersByLastName(string lastname)
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new AzureAuthenticationProvider());
        string filter = String.Format("startswith(surname, '{0}')", lastname);
        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter(filter).GetAsync(); 
        return users;
    }
}
public class AzureAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    private string _azureDomain = "myDevDom.onmicrosoft.com";

    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            string clientId = "2b823c67-1b0d-4a10-a9e1-737142516f5q";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxx";

            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + _azureDomain + "/oauth2/token");

            ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credentials);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

}

My project is an Azure functionApp version 1.0 with http triger.

I have already try to delete bin folder and rebuild and it doesnt work.
I don't know how to solve this issue any ideas ?

Bests Regards,
RobinLotz

Comment: can you convert error message to english

Answer (score 0):

> I have already try to delete bin folder and rebuild and it doesnt work. I don't know how to solve this issue any ideas ?

I also could reproduce the issue that you metioned, if I use the code you mentioned.

If we want to init the ***GraphServiceClient***, we could use the following code to do that. It works on my side correctly.

```
 string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
 string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
 string tenantId = "tenant Id ";
 string clientId = "client id";
 string secret = "secret key";
 authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
 var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
 var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: if i try your way i have an error :

Erreur CS1729 'AuthenticationContext' does not contain a constructor that accepts arguments 11 FunctionApp7 C:\Users\\source\repos\FunctionApp7\FunctionApp7\Function1.cs 95 Actif

and: 

Error CS1061 'AuthenticationContext' does not contain a definition for 'AcquireTokenAsync' and no 'AcquireTokenAsync' extension method that accepts a first argument of type 'AuthenticationContext' was found (using directive or assembly reference) missing?)

Which assembly did you used ?

Comment: ok i find out but now i get this and i dont understand why :
"error": { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user. Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints. Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps."

Comment: It seems that you use the native azure AD application, please use the Web API Azure AD application

Comment: Its not possible to do so with an native Azure AD application ?

Comment: I test it with Azure AD WebApp api Application.